# How to identify slowing code in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got an appli where images are touched and replaced once touched.
not quiet complex but the response time of the touch and the replacement is really high and I'd like to find a way to detect where/why the appli is slowing down...

what could I do to identify the code portion that is slowing the app ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sampling the application with Instruments.app?
It should give you lots of details about your application's activity.